# Confused, is ROS needed if all I want is to send motors signals?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Confused, is ROS needed if all I want is to send motors signals? Like send 10110 to make a motor turn clockwise. Does my robot/microcontroller come with the code I'll need when I buy a robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224138/confused,-is-ros-needed-if-all-i-want-is-to-send-motors-signals?/) by [ADVANCESSSS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25570/advancessss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No; ROS is not necessary if you just want to write code to communicate with a microcontroller or motor controller.

I don't know if every robot comes with code or not. You should check the manufacturer's description and the documentation for any hardware you're considering to see if it comes with code or not.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ADVANCESSSS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25570/advancessss/) on 2016-01-14**:
If I can send a motor signals so easy, why can't I receive motor/other signals so easy? As a sensor? Is there any I can buy and use as sensors? I don't want to have to install ROS to get sensory input.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-14**:
Depending on your sensor, you probably don't need ROS to receive the sensor data. Why do you think you do?

**Comment by [ADVANCESSSS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25570/advancessss/) on 2016-01-14**:
Because I'm very desperate to put my AI in a robot that has camera & accelometor & earphones or other sensor/s and I was told I can only get sensors's sensory input by ROS/OpenCV(for camera), so I'm thinking I'm stuck with only vision or maybe "other" types of sensors unless I can get them all.

**Comment by [ADVANCESSSS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25570/advancessss/) on 2016-01-15**:
^ ?.......

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-15**:
You've been told wrong; ROS is not a requirement for interfacing with sensors. It can make things easier, but it's not required.

**Comment by [ADVANCESSSS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25570/advancessss/) on 2016-01-15**:
So the robot I buy CAN give me the commands I need to get the sensors senses? Ex. "prepare getSound(agr sound moment)"

**Comment by [ADVANCESSSS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25570/advancessss/) on 2016-01-16**:
^ Read my last comment - Just making sure your answer is correct.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-16**:
Yes; depending on the robot. Do your research and make sure that whatever you get provides an API that you're comfortable with.